# Adding multiple textviews in Linear Layout inside <android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I want to show multiple text views in one line (horizontally) inside card view (number of views are dynamic for each card, fetched from server). For that I'm using a linear layout in card view like,

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llReader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>
```

And inside adapter(I am using recyclerview adapter) while populating in onBindViewHolder method i'm doing like this,

```
for (i=0;i<array.size();i++){ // arraysize is different for each card
  //create a new texview
  // set text of that textview accordingly
  // add it to linear layout (ll.addview(tv)
}
```

Then I prepare the apk and test it. All cards are getting populated correctly. So far so good.

But after few time, when all cards get populated, I noticed that all linear layouts merged and all cards are having linear layout of all other cards. What can be the reason and how to solve it?

P.S. Initially I tried with having a single text view instead of linear layout and keep on adding text into a string inside for loop and then call setText method of text view. This was working fine i.e., it was showing details related to that particular card only. But now I can't use the same as each text view is having an image as well, so new text views will be like (Image + someText). Please suggest me if there is any other way of doing so than using Linear layout.

Answer (score 0):

If your original code with only TextViews is working, you can use TextView with [compound drawables](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)).

Then you wouldn't need an ImageView at all. Just add `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/yourImage"` (or `textView. setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(yourImage, null, null, null)` for adding dynamically) to your TextView.

As for your current implementation, it's not possible without looking at your code as to how you are dynamically adding the TextView.